# Convert EPOCH time to MYSQL TIMESTAMP using NODEJS -LAMBDA

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

```
var epochtime = "1610950344";
var datevar = new Date(epochtime *1000);
var mytime = datevar.toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
console.log("DATEEEEEEEEEE : "+mytime);
 
const query = `INSERT INTO MYTIME (MY_TIME, NAME) VALUES ('${mytime}', 'ANN')`;  

updateDB(query); //Custom function to create a connection and insert the data into the table
```

MY_TIME is defined as TIMESTAMP in mysql schema. The above query is working except for the MY_TIME field. When mytime gets inserted, it changes the values to "0000-00-00 00:00:00" in mysql. Why is this happening? Is there anything wrong with the data conversion. Please help

Answer (score 3):

You can simply query like this:

```
INSERT INTO MYTIME (MY_TIME, NAME) VALUES (FROM_UNIXTIME(${epochtime}), 'ANN')
```

Comment: Thanks Ehsan. This works if the epoch time is 10 digits. in my case it is 13 digits ( including milliseconds i guess). So i used Math.floor(epochtime / 1000) before calling FROM_UNIXTIME. Is that correct?

Comment: @Ann Consider accepting this answer if it helped you. It is a way of saying thank you on StackOverflow. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers